# How do I take original files in one directory, shuffle the names to be randomized for the actual file, and move them without overwriting

Tags: python, list, random, file-rename

I am working on taking the names of daily email list files for one week and randomizing the names/days of the files for the next week to where they wont get contacted on the same day of the week. I've been using random.choice() with the directory to change the name of the file to one of the existing ones in the original folder and moving it to a new folder, but when I get to the third or fourth file it either overwrites or stops completely.

```
import os
import random
import shutil

def shuffle_and_move_files(source_folder, destination_folder):
    if not os.path.exists(source_folder):
        print(f"Source folder '{source_folder}' does not exist.")
        return

    if not os.path.exists(destination_folder):
        os.makedirs(destination_folder)

    files_list = os.listdir(source_folder)
    random.shuffle(files_list)

    for filename in files_list:
        source_path = os.path.join(source_folder, filename)
        if os.path.isfile(source_path):

            random_name = random.choice(file_list)
            
            destination_path = os.path.join(destination_folder, random_name)
            
            shutil.move(source_path, destination_path)
            
            print(f"Moved '{filename}' to '{random_name}'")
```

Comment: `random.choice(file_list)` This does not remove the chosen filename from the list -- it remains in the list, and might be chosen again later.  Perhaps this is the cause.

Comment: There is nothing in this code that would cause a filename (basename) to change. Also, calling random.choice on a list that you've just shuffled is pointless